# Challenging: code a python code that goes from 1 to n that takes n, a pair number(2,4,6,8 etc.)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to increment a pair number by 2 starting at 1, but the last digit doesn't go all the way to n, why ? is this feasible ?  I want the output to go from 1 to the inputed pair number and then the inputed pair number back to 1. Let's say if we input 20, the code will go from 1 to 19, then 20 to 2, which isn't what I want, I want it to go from 1 to 20, then 20 to 1, what is the problem here ?   Please write a code that prints out 1 to n in increment of 2 . eg(n = 12, 1 to n: 1,3,5,7,9,12)

```
for x in range (1,n,2):
     print(x,end=' ')
print()
for x in range (n,1,-2):
     print(x,end=' ')
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `range` function's [second argument is exclusive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range). That means it will go up to but not include that number:

```
r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop
```

This follows the principle of least surprise. If you want to get the range of all indices in a list ten items long, you wouldn't expect to get eleven values.

You have a second issue, which is that if you want the range of all the odd numbers from 1 to 20, those are:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
```

The number 20 will never be included in that because the next step is 21. It will always go from 1 to 19. Consider how your example `n = 12, 1 to n: 1,3,5,7,9,12` is incorrect: the numbers in that sequence when you step by 2 would be `1,3,5,7,9,11`. You can never get to the number 12 when you start at 1 and increment by 2 each time. That is just math.

Comment: Could you fix the mistake and make it so that it goes from 1 to n, then n to 1 ?

Comment: @Mr.Green Updated my answer - you can't get that result if you're stepping by two.

Comment: It still isn't working

Comment: I have to step by 2

Comment: @Mr.Green It can't work without violating mathematics. See my updated answer.

Comment: If n = 20,  and the increment is 2, I want it to go from 1,3,5,7,9,

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your detailed answer but would it be possible to code it in a different manner ?